# How can I use the Input System Package's Split-Screen?

Tags: unity

I've made a simple local multiplayer game with Unity's Input System Package. Players can join the game with a keyboard or a gamepad. Currently, the game has only one static camera. And I know that there's an option in "Player Input Manager" component to enable the Split-Screen feature. But how does that work?

[image: Player Input Manager Component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Input System's Split-Screen feature is so handy to use. Check the Split-Screen option. Then, some other options will be displayed in the component as below:

[image: Input System's Component]

**Maintain Aspect Ratio**: When set to `true`, split cameras will force to have the same aspect ratio as before splitting (normal display).

**Set Fixed Number**: If enabled, the game screen will be forced to have certain parts, even if there are not that many players assigned.

**Screen Rectangle**: According to [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/Components.html#playerinputmanager-component:%7E:text=The%20normalized%20screen%20rectangle%20available%20for%20allocating%20player%20split%2Dscreens%20into.): The normalized screen rectangle available for allocating player split-screens into.

After configuring the "Player Input Manager" component, you have to make some changes to the player's "Player Input" component. You have to put both player & a proper camera (the current main camera should be fine) as children of a GameObject, which I name *Player Camera Group* as below:

[image: Player Camera Group in hierarchy window]

Make sure to make it a prefab, then get back to the GameObject holding the "Player Input Manager" component, & assign the *Player Camera Group* as `Player Prefab`.

You're done. Now if you play the game, everything should be perfectly working. Also, check out this [Unity Document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/Components.html#:%7E:text=automatically%20join%20them.-,Split%2Dscreen,set%20this%20up%20using%20the%20PlayerInput%2C%20InputSystemUIInputModule%20and%20MultiplayerEventSystem%20components.,-PlayerInputManager%20notifications) to learn more about the "Player Input Manager" & Split-Screen features.